# typescript import statement is evaluating to null at runtime with node.js

Tags: typescript

I think I'm doing an importing/exporting incorrectly as I get no typescript compiler error but get a runtime error trying to reference my class `ActivityType` from another file.

the error occurs when calling `Experience.save()`:

```
import Activities = require('../models/Activities');
import ActivityType = Activities.ActivityType;

export class Experience extends BaseModel {

        static save(experience:Experience) {
            console.log(ActivityType.created) //this throws an error saying ActivityType is null
            experience.validate();
        }
}
```

and in `models/Activities.ts`:

```
export class ActivityType {
    static created = 'created';
    static updated = 'updated';
    static commented = 'commented';
    static uploaded = 'uploaded';
    static joined = 'joined';
    static followed = 'followed';
    static chat = 'chat';
}
```

I tried wrapping the export statements in Activities.ts in a `module` block as well, e.g.

```
module Activities {
  export class ActivityType {
    static created = 'created';
    static updated = 'updated';
    static commented = 'commented';
    static uploaded = 'uploaded';
    static joined = 'joined';
    static followed = 'followed';
    static chat = 'chat';
  }
}
```

but then that gave me Typescript errors in the the import statements.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reason why ActivityType would be `null` - that usually has to be set explicitly.  I'm not even sure how ActivityType could be undefined based on the code you've provided.

One guess is that you might be getting a `Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` error.  If that's the case, you may be chasing the wrong thing and are actually experiencing an out-of-order issue with your use of the `extends` keyword.  If you have a base class and a class that extends it in the same TypeScript file, the base class has to come first.

This code should work when compiling to ES5 and CommonJS:

**models/Activities.ts**

```
export class ActivityType {
    static created = 'created';
    // etc...
}

console.log("Activities loaded");
```

**code/test.ts**

```
import Activities = require('../models/Activities');
// Using the import keyword doesn't change the emit, so this
// could just be var here.
import ActivityType = Activities.ActivityType;

class BaseModel {
    public thing = "hi";
}

export class Experience extends BaseModel {
    static save(experience:Experience) {
        console.log(ActivityType.created)
    }
}

const ex = new Experience();

Experience.save(ex);
```

If you switch the order of declaration of `BaseModel` and `Experience`, it will work with TypeScript, but fail at runtime.

If that's not it, please provide some more of the emitted code.  For example, how/where is BaseModel declared?

Comment: digging around a bit more it looks like it was a misleading error and is a circular dependency.  My Experience class was importing ActivityType and ActivityType was importing Experience.  Commenting out the reference and call to the Experience from the Activites.ts let it resolve correctly... the error message just didn't suggest it was the circular dependency and didn't have ca compile time error